# Create a Stored Procedure for Polybase - Cannot pass in parameter

Tags: azure-synapse

*[Posting question from customer]*

I would like to do periodic loads into SQL Data Warehouse using Polybase.  My plan is to create a Stored Procedure that takes in the "LOCATION" parameter for Create External Table, but the parameter is failing due to syntax.  Here's a sample of the code I've written:

```
alter PROCEDURE CETFromNewLocation
as
begin
Declare @location varchar(100)='data/2015/2015831';
Create External TABLE stg_tbl (
    [DateId] int NULL
)
WITH (
LOCATION= @location,
      DATA_SOURCE = my_external_source,
      FILE_FORMAT = my_external_file_format,
      REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,
      REJECT_VALUE = 0
)
end
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
> Parse error at line: 25, column: 16: Incorrect syntax near
> '@location'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use variables in DDL statements. Try using dynamic sql - form the string for your DDL and execute it using sp_executesql stored procedure like below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CETFromNewLocation    AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @location varchar(100)

SET @location = 'data/2015/2015831'

DECLARE @CreateExternalTableString varchar(100)

SET @CreateExternalTableString = 
                                    'Create External TABLE stg_tbl (
                                                  [DateId] int NULL
                                    )
                                    WITH (LOCATION = ' + @location + ',                                      
                                             DATA_SOURCE = my_external_source,
                                             FILE_FORMAT = my_external_file_format,
                                             REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,
                                             REJECT_VALUE = 0
                                    )'

EXEC sp_executesql @CreateExternalTableString

END
```